# replacing よう with みたい

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances, synonyms

Is it always possible to replace　よう with みたい?

For example in this sentence:

> 思うようにはいかないものだ。

Would

> 思うみたいにはいかないものだ 。

work as well?

I've read many times that these two can be interchangeable, but it seems that's not always the case. Are there are any rules explaining when one of them sounds better or is grammatically correct and the other doesn't or is not?

Answer (score 1):

Despite their meanings being similar, there is distinction that lies in their usage. みたい is used in speech in which has a casual tone while よう is used less often like in writing (like letters).

I have included some videos for reference:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=An6sKwhUH48

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uHIaZD23-U